# Git describe detached head

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to migrate from Buildbot to Gitlab CI. Everything works fine, except getting version number from git. We were using

```
git describe --always --tags --abbrev=4
```

command in conjunction with reasonable tag names (like "1.0"). It worked flawlessly with buildbot, but for some reason gitlab-ci checkouts to HEAD revision making the working copy to be in "detached head" state, so beforementioned command returns ugly version names (like "53ab" instead of say "1.0-50-g53ab"). Is there a way to get commit description with tags in this case?

Comment: Where is the version number supposed to come from? A tag that is already present in the repository?

Comment: Daniel, yes, exactly.

Comment: Are you sure the tag is present in the remote repository? Because it’s working perfectly fine for me with a detached head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, there was a `filter-branch` problem (which I did prior to migration to cleanup some minor errors): commit hashes changed after it, so tags existed, but pointed to non-existing commits.